# Knockout validatedObservable gives me isValid is not defined

Tags: knockout.js

```
self.selectedAddressBook = ko.validatedObservable();

var emptyEntry = ko.validatedObservable(new AddressBookEntryViewModel());

self.currentEntry = ko.computed(function () {
    if (!self.selectedAddressBook())
        return emptyEntry();
    return self.selectedAddressBook();
});


self.addressBookEntries = ko.observableArray(null);
```

and I populate the entries on an ajax call :

```
var entries = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (e) {
    return new AddressBookEntryViewModel(e);
})
self.addressBookEntries(entries);
```

on the edit form of `currentEntry` the save button have a binding to isValid():

```
<button data-bind="enable: isValid()" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I have a form select that the user picks an option like this :

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="enable: addressBookEntries(), options : addressBookEntries,
               optionsText: 'address',
               value: selectedAddressBook,
               optionsCaption: 'Select address'"></select>
```

when I have no `selectedAddressBook` the emptyEntry works without a problem, but as soon as the user picks an option from the select, it throws an error with `isValid is not defined`

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it so the option selected from the select element can be a validatedObservable.

Comment: `isValid` is an observable belonging to `selectedAddressBook`. Try `enable: selectedAddressBook.isValid`.

Comment: Let us know if your issue got resolved or not.

Comment: unfortunatelly no. Have to show this today so I went another route, and have 2 separate objects. one for the new entry and another for the select element ones. Couldn't make it to work. Removing the `validatedObservable` to simple `observable` worked fine (of course, without the isValid functionability) :(